# C++ WinApi Tables

Tags: c++, winapi, tabular

I am new to Stack Overflow and C++ programming and I have come to a problem when trying to make a basic application to start learning C++. The problem I am having is that I am trying to make a table like:

[image]

so that I can store some fields/values for my application to function but when searching I couldn't find what I was looking for, is this in the WinApi or do I have to make it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 storing data and viewing it usually required different approaches

2 if you are looking for table-like GUI widget then List View (with report style) may be useful, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737(v=vs.85).aspx